# SSRS Get number of filtered groups

Tags: reporting-services, count, grouping, aggregate-functions, fetchxml

Working with dynamics 365 reports has brought me to the next issue.
Because FetchXML doesn't support NOT EXISTS condition, i have to filter data inside report.
The case is that I have like 7000 rows and I group them by account (around 2000 groups).
And used filter on group.
And after that i've got:
| account |  data      |
|----------| ----------|
| apple___  | some_data |
| samsung| more_data |
| lg_______ | next_data |
So after grouping and filtering i have only 3 groups (accounts).
But how to achieve this value (3) in report?
`CountDistict(Field!account.Value)` includes all nonfiltered accounts.
`CountDistict(Field!account.Value, "filteredAccGroup")` outside the group throws "The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox145’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function."
Have no other ideas.
I need the count (or number) of all filtered groups. Current index of group would also be nice.
Thanks.

**Solution:**
Found the solution. But not sure this is the optimal one.
Outside the group:

```
CountDistinct(iif(min(Fields!date.Value, "account_group") >= CDate("01/01/2021"),
Fields!account.Value, nothing))
```

Under iif is the condition i have filtered the group.

Comment: How are you filtering the data?

Comment: it doesn't matter actually. if you wanna know, i use iif(min(Fields!date.Value ,"account_group") >= CDate("01/01/2021"), true, false)

Comment: So you mean you have added a filter in the dataset filter properties? If not please elaborate.

Comment: no, i added filter on group properties

Comment: This is exactly why I asked you "How are you filtering the data?" . If you filter at the dataset, the answer below will work

Answer (score 1):

Outside the group:

> ```
> CountDistinct(iif(min(Fields!date.Value, "account_group") >= CDate("01/01/2021"),
> Fields!account.Value, nothing))
> ```

Under **iif** is the condition i have filtered the group.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataset is called `DataSet1` then the following should work .

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!account.Value, "DataSet1")
```

As usual , the scope has to be in quotes and is case sensitive.

Comment: it does not work, because i did not filter dataset. this function returns all 2000 accounts, but i need only 3, that in group